# Find a new matrix considering the values of one of the columns

Tags: matlab

I have a `m-rows` by `n-columns` matrix in matlab. One of the columns (#2) contain the values of `VIP` and I want to obtain the matrix that only contain the rows of the original matrix where `VIP>1`.

How can I find this new matrix?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15051275/logical-indexing-instead-of-find

Comment: `matrix(matrix(:,2)>1,:)`

Comment: I am agree with @patrik, take a look at the link he sent you! You want the rows where `VIP>1`. In other words you want to remove the rows from your `mxn` matrix that where `VIP<1`. Or take a look to the suggestion made by @Luis Mendo (+1)